# What am I doing wrong? Random Number Guessing Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

First off, I am thankful for any answers you may provide.

Anyways, I am a beginner in Python and to programming in general. I've tried to create my own Random Number Guessing game where the computer picks a random number between 1-15, yada yada.

My problem is when I try to tell the user if their guess is too low or too high the program either terminates without informing the user if they are correct or not. Or it just keeps looping through.

> Too Low, please guess again: 14
>
> Correct! You've guessed my number!
>
> Too Low, please guess again: 12
>
> Too Low, please guess again: 1
>
> Too Low, please guess again:

Here is my entire code for this program:

```
import random
from time import sleep

number = random.randint(1,15)
play = input("Hello! Would you like to play (Y/N) ")

if play in('y', 'Y'):
    sleep(.75)

    print("I've chosen a number between 1 and 15.") 
    sleep(.5)

    guess = int(input("What is my number? "))

    while guess >= number:
        guess = int(input("Too High, please guess again: "))
        if guess == number:
            print("Correct! You've guessed my number!")

    while guess <= number:
        guess = int(input("Too Low, please guess again: "))
    
        if guess == number:
            print("Correct! You've guessed my number!")
        
else:
    exit
```

Again, thanks for any answers!

Comment: homework? You need to figure out how to combine your two loops into one. Also while this one was easy to spot it's a good idea to explain what your program does, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look into combining loops right away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your looping logic is a bit twisted.

```
while guess >= number:
    guess = int(input("Too High, please guess again: "))
    if guess == number:
        print("Correct! You've guessed my number!")

while guess <= number:
    guess = int(input("Too Low, please guess again: "))

    if guess == number:
        print("Correct! You've guessed my number!")
```

1. You loop while the guess is too high. A low guess interrupts this.
2. You loop while the guess is too low. A high guess interrupts this.

So if we first do a low guess, then a high guess, but we are still incorrect, we've escaped the `while` pair and can't try again.

Instead, try this single looping construct:

```
while guess != number:
```

And inside that, `if` for `<=`, `==`, and `>=`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If I guess low, it puts me in the 'guess below number' loop. If I ever guess above the number, the loop just ends and dumps me out of the program.

What you need to do is have a combined loop of while guess != number, and check both for above and below and equal within the loop.,

Comment: Ohhh! I didn't even think about doing that. Looks like I need a little more practice. lol :). Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Change your whiles as follows:

```
while guess != number:
    if (guess > number):
        print("Too High!")
    else:
        print("Too Low!")
    guess = int(input("Please guess again: "))

print("Correct! You guessed my number!")
```